# How iptables SNAT deal with src port dilemma between port translation fr local ip and DNAT rule that forwards all traffic to the same local ip?

Tags: networking, router, iptables, nat, dmz

Say we have a Linux based router with WAN interface `eth0` ip addr `4.3.2.1` (w/ whatever gw ip) and LAN interface `eth1` ip addr `192.168.51.1/24`, which means we need an iptables rule below to make the router or nat gateway to work (together with ipv4 forwarding enabled in sysctl):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.51.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then we've got a new device connected on the LAN interface, with ip addr `192.168.51.2/24` and gw `192.168.51.1`, so it could connect to public internet through the gw as expected.

Now the device want to access a web server on `1.1.1.1`, the http request traffic should be from src like `192.168.51.2:40960` (a random src port) to dst `1.1.1.1:80`, and when the traffic goes thru the router, it should be changed to src like `4.3.2.1:50961` (another random src port selected and recorded on the **Network Translation Port Table**) to dst `1.1.1.1:80`, right?

Then when the response heads back, the packet with dst `4.3.2.1:50961` will be reversed back to `192.168.51.2:40960` based on the **NAPT** and well received. Everything's working so far so well.

---

Now the Problem comes, we want to setup the device `192.168.51.2` as a DMZ host. We add one more iptables rule like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 192.168.51.2
```

Now let's imagine the device want to access the same web service again. This time when the response comes back from `1.1.1.1:80` to dst `4.3.2.1:50961`, we need to know which path it should go - either `192.168.51.2:50961` according to the **DNAT rule** we just set, or the `192.168.51.2:40960` based on the **NAPT record** when the traffic went out from the WAN?

Which one has... let's say - higher priority... to process the packets of the response?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw, `MASQUERADE` works in the `POSTROUTING` chain, not `PREROUTING`.

Comment: Thanks @TomYan for reminding me that, that's clearly wrong which I should correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing conntrack states (the "NAPT records") always have priority over any `-t nat` rules.

If you remember, the `-t nat` table is only visited by *one* packet per connection – that's because any packet (whether forward or reply) that matches an existing conntrack state is processed according to stored values in that state, without consulting the iptables NAT rules at all.

Comment: Appreciate your instant and clear answer, @u1686_grawity. And experiments show same behavior as you asserted. So would you mind to let me know where to get manual or articles as you mentioned "if you remember" - which I don't - since I've used conntrack features like `NEW` or `ESTABLISHED` but not enough in depth.